# Script only works if I restart the shell

Tags: python

So I wrote a script which gets parameters from input (by hand) 
and it writes it in a text file. My only problem is that the text from the input won't appear in the txt file,  only if i restart the shell manually. What would you recommend to try to fix this, so I don't  have to restart the the shell manially all the time?

Well the script is simple, because I'm beginer :D

```
# input to txt

text_from_input = input()
file=open("testfile.txt","w")
file.write(text_from_input)
file.close
```

Comment: Start by showing us the script.

Comment: @JohnAnderson a stripped down, minimal version of the script, which still demonstrates the problem. See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Are you seeing any error messages? Are you using Python3 or Python2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code, you're referencing the `close` method of your file object, but you're not calling it. That means the file isn't closed until you close the interpreter (you could probably also get the same effect by using `del file` or rebinding the variable to some other object).

To fix the problem, you can call `close` just by adding parentheses: `file.close()`

Or better yet, use a [`with` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files):

```
with open("testfile.txt","w") as file:
    file.write(text_from_input)
# the file will be closed here
```

When the indented block following the `with` ends, the file will be closed automatically. It will happen even if you exit the block unexpectedly, due to an exception.